# Display Image together with title and description as results from database using search bar

Tags: php, mysql, database

Need help to echo image together with the title and description in the code below, when search it display title and description that i insert in the database, i want to display image together with title and description when search in the search bar

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 

$min_length = 1;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ 

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 


    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);


    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products
        WHERE (`title` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`description` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());


    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 

        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){


            echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['description']."</p>";

        }

    }
    else{ 
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ 
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
```

?>

Comment: I am using xampp database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As if I understand it right then the problem is you're not printing your image

```
 while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
            echo '<img src=".$result['image']." >'; 
            echo "<p><h3>".$results['title']."</h3>".$results['description']."</p>";

        }
```

> Mysql api will be completely removed in PHP 7
>
> And please use mysqli parametrized query or pdo See the bobby tables
>   http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Thanks! i tried ur code and make some changes and it works! after added BLOD image in database i use this: `echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $results['image'] ).'"/>';`

Answer (score 0):

With that, I think you need also to store the links of the images in the database. Then echo the path of the image.